# FindRoot with vector functions

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation, numerics

I'm trying to solve a system of non-linear equations with `FindRoot`, and I get the answer, but also a

> ```
> *partd* (part spec longer than depth of object)
> ```

error. This throws me off and makes me think it's poor programming. Is there a way to code this such that I don't get this message?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
F[x_] := {x[[2]]*x[[3]], -x[[1]]*x[[3]], -0.51 x[[1]]*x[[2]]}
dt = 0.1;
xi = {0, 1, 1};
xj = {x[1], x[2], x[3]};
FindRoot[xj == xi + dt*F[xj], {xj, xi}]

Part::partd: "Part specification xj[[2]] is longer than depth of object."
Part::partd: "Part specification xj[[3]] is longer than depth of object."
Part::partd: "Part specification xj[[1]] is longer than depth of object."

{{x[1], x[2], x[3]} -> {0.0985269, 0.990196, 0.995024}}
```

Comment: You can change `FindRoot[xj == xi + dt*F[xj], Transpose[{xj, xi}]]`.

Comment: double square brackets [[]] are used for list.

Comment: @Algohi Oh I know, but how else could I define this vector-valued function? I mean how could I define F(x) = (x(2)*x(3),...) without using [[]]?

Answer (score 8):

Define the helper functions and variables like this:

```
F[x_] := {x[[2]] x[[3]], -x[[1]] x[[3]], -0.51 x[[1]] x[[2]]}
dt = 0.1;
xi = {0, 1, 1};
```

Do *not* define `xj` since you need to use that as a single symbol in `FindRoot`.

Now this equation, `xj == xi + dt F[xj]` makes sense if we substitute a concrete vector value for `xj`.  If we don't the equation will still evaluate with `xj` being a symbol (i.e. treated as a scalar), and cause errors for several obvious reasons:

```
In[5]:= xj == xi + dt F[xj]

During evaluation of In[5]:= Part::partd: Part specification xj[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>

During evaluation of In[5]:= Part::partd: Part specification xj[[3]] is longer than depth of object. >>

During evaluation of In[5]:= Part::partd: Part specification xj[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

During evaluation of In[5]:= General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[5]= xj == {0.1 xj[[2]] xj[[3]], 1 - 0.1 xj[[1]] xj[[3]], 1 - 0.051 xj[[1]] xj[[2]]}
```

The solution is to ask `FindRoot` not to evaluate the equation before it substitutes a value for `xj`:

```
In[6]:= FindRoot[xj == xi + dt F[xj], {{xj, xi}}, Evaluated -> False]

Out[6]= {xj -> {0.0985269, 0.990196, 0.995024}}
```

Yes, unfortunately using `FindRoot` with vector-variables is a bit less convenient then one would like.

---

I just realized that the `Evaluated` option of `FindRoot` is not documented.  Here's a general and robust solution to these types of problems, *without* using the `Evaluated` option:

- Use `FindRoot` with a single function, like this: `FindRoot[fun[x], {x, x0}]`.  It will find the value of `x` for which `fun[x]` is zero (where zero can be a vector/tensor of zeros).
- Make sure you give a starting value `x0`, and that `x0` is a numerical vector (matrix, tensor, etc.) of the correct length (and dimension).
- Make sure `fun[x]` does not evaluate if `x` does not have a (vector-)value.  If you evaluate `fun[x]` on its own, and `x` is a symbol, it should return as-is.  To achieve this, define `fun` as

  ```
  Clear[fun]
  fun[x_?VectorQ] := ...
  ```

  or as

  ```
  Clear[fun]     
  fun[x_ ? (VectorQ[#, NumericQ]&)] := ...
  ```

  to require not only that `x` be a vector but also that each element of that vector be a numerical quantity (i.e. not a symbol)

Let's apply this to your problem:

```
In[13]:= fun[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := F[x] dt + xi - x

In[14]:= FindRoot[fun[x], {x, xi}]    
Out[14]= {x -> {0.0985269, 0.990196, 0.995024}}
```

Further reading (not the same problem but essentially analogous):

- http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: This is very help full, Thanks a lot