# FindRoot with vector function

Tags: equation-solving, vector

I have trouble with `FindRoot` for vector variables, I have search MMA SE find a [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51668/findroot-with-vector-functions). in [Szabolcs‘s code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51668/findroot-with-vector-functions), Vector `FindRoot` realized by the `Evaluated` option of FindRoot.

Here is my code,`Evaluated -> False` not work.

```
deltat = 1*^-3;
integrator[x_, y_, {x0_, y0_}] := {x[1], y[1]} /. 
   FindRoot[{x[1] - x[0] == {1, 1, 1}, 
      y[1] - y[0] == {1, 1, 1}} /. {x[0] -> x0, y[0] -> y0}, {{x[1], 
      x0}, {y[1], y0}}, Evaluated -> False];
integrator[x, y, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}];
```

I have test when the variables is scalar, but it fails in Vector variables.

Any comments will be very appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that something like `x + {1, 1}` automatically evaluates to `{1+x, 1+x}`, and now making `x` a vector causes issues. In your case that means that `x[1] - x[0]` becomes `{x[1], x[1], x[1]}` and [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) doesn't work. One idea is to put all the explicit vectors on one side of the equation and implicit vectors on the other:

```
integrator[x_, y_, {x0_, y0_}] := {x[1], y[1]} /. FindRoot[
    {x[1] == x0 + {1,1,1}, y[1] == y0 + {1,1,1}},
    {
        {x[1], x0},
        {y[1], y0}
    }
];

integrator[x,y,{{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}]
```

> {{1., 1., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}}

Another possibility is to add equations for `x[0]` and `y[0]`:

```
integrator[x_, y_, {x0_, y0_}] := {x[1], y[1]} /. FindRoot[
    {x[1] -x[0] == {1,1,1}, y[1] - y[0] == {1,1,1}, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0},
    {
        {x[0], x0},
        {y[0], y0},
        {x[1], x0},
        {y[1], y0}
    }
];

integrator[x,y,{{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}]
```

> {{1., 1., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}}

Comment: Thank you, follow your idea, I have test this code and find some issues and maybe fixed it(in this question). any advice will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

@Carl Woll, thank you!

I think the answer should combine [Carl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258484/findroot-with-vector-function/258511#258511) and [Szabolcs‘s code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51668/findroot-with-vector-functions). In Carl's code, it seems not work when equation right-hand with `x[1]` which need to `FindRoot`.

Here is the example code, which return error.

```
integrator[x_, y_, {x0_, y0_}] := {x[1], y[1]} /. 
   FindRoot[{x[1] == x0 + x[1]\[Cross]{1, 1, 1}, 
     y[1] == y0 + {1, 1, 1}}, {{x[1], x0}, {y[1], y0}}];

integrator[x, y, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}]
```

So ,if we put `Evaluated` option

```
integrator[x_, y_, {x0_, y0_}] := {x[1], y[1]} /. 
   FindRoot[{x[1] == x0 + x[1]\[Cross]{1, 1, 1}, 
     y[1] == y0 + {1, 1, 1}}, {{x[1], x0}, {y[1], y0}}, 
    Evaluated -> False];

integrator[x, y, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}]
```

I didn't know why we should take `Evaluated` option, but it works for general form.

Thanks to Carl and Szabolcs again.